# Entity relashionship with 1-to-1 relation on both sides

Tags: entity-relationship

When modeling with entity-association diagram, I had this relationship which I found weird, I wonder if it's allowed in this model.

```
+----------+      =-------=         +-------------+  
+ Driver   +--1,1-=  HAS  =---1,1---+ performance +  
+----------+      =-------=         +-------------+
```

Two entities Vehicle and performance and relationship has.

So A Driver must have one and only performance and vice versa.
I wonder if i must merge these two entities into one entity, but semantically this seems wrong, a Driver is not a performance.
In application level, Performance allow to give a points to a driver in order to class Drivers.

Comment: What are the attributes of *performance*?

Comment: It's just an example, the actual schem is that i have Driver instead of Vehicule, and Performance, attributes of Performance are worked_days, missed_days, errors_number... it provides informations to calculate the performance of a Driver.

Comment: I modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is vaguely similar to a bridge table, which would be used to represent a many-to-many relationship:

```
drivers ----- many / many ----- performance
```

transformed into:

```
driver ----- 1 / many ----- bridge table ----- many / 1 ----- performance
```

but that is not quite what is happening here.

In this case, the middle table seems to play no useful role and should probably be removed. Assuming that `performance` is a child table of `driver` (so `performance` records include a foreign key that references `driver`), then it would likely ok to remove `performance` completely and add those columns directly to `driver`.

If there are other tables that reference `performance` such that it would be burdensome to remove that table, you could keep it as a separate table, but just make the references point directly to `driver`.

Comment: In entity-relationship model, the attributes must be coherent with the entity, they should indicate the same abstraction or object... this is the reason that this is confusing me, so i understand that It's OK to join these two entities despite representing different concepts.

Comment: But do they *really* represent different concepts? `Performance` is a weak entity-- it depends on `Driver` and wouldn't make sense on it's own. And it's a 1-to-1 relationship, so we know that a `performance` record and a `driver` record are uniquely tied. Unless there are some attribiutes in `Performance` that for some reason cannot be added to `Driver`, it seems that performance is just another group of data points that belong to the strong `Driver` entity, and could reasonably be combined.